# How to save a response from a Haml "= select_tag"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm not  getting any way to get/save the response form the given select_tag.

```
@status = Status.values
= select_tag :status, content_tag(:option, 'status', :value=>"") + options_for_select( @status )
```

Comment: very vague questions. add more details what you tried and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've made a form , in which i have two fields source and destination , now user enters source and destination fields in from and clicks the button , i want to pass the input he has given to the controller

Comment: Don't add additional information as comments. Instead, edit your question, adding the new information as if it'd been there all along, without using "edit" or "update" type tags as we can tell what changed and when if we need to. Readability is more important than keeping track of when things changed.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, the status is submitted to the controller. Usually, either the `create` action or the `update` action will receive this data. You can see it in the `params` in the controller when you look at the stdout in the terminal which runs your server or explicitly print it again:

```rb
def create 
  puts params.inspect
end
```

To learn more about parameters read "[Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)".